# How to mount from Windows 10 host to Linux guest via NFS?

Tags: virtualbox, nfs

I have ZorinOS 15 Lite as a Linux guest on my Windows 10 host machine.
The aim is to mount from my Windows 10 host to this Linux NFS server.
The NFS client setup on Windows 10 is done.
The NFS server setup on Zorin OS is done.
But still there are problems with mounting.
On Zorin guest `nfs-kernel-server` installed and edited `/etc/exports/` file:

```
/data   192.168.0.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure)
```

`/data/` - the folder which I want to be shared between Win10 host and Zorin guest.
`192.168.0.0/24` - share directory for IPs between `192.168.0.0` and`192.168.255.255`

Doing `ipconfig` I know this:
Windows host IP address - `192.168.1.66`
Linux guest IP address - `192.168.56.1`
When I'm trying to mount from Win10 host, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Alibek Kaparov>mount -o nolock -o anon \\192.168.56.1\data I:
Network Error - 53

Type 'NET HELPMSG 53' for more information.
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm not experienced with NFS and VBox.

Comment: I would temporarily relax security by changing the IP address in your `/etc/exports` to `*` and restarting the NFS server. Then run `showmount -e localhost` to see exactly what ZorinOS is exporting, and to whom.

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out in comments, thanks Mark Setchell, I changed IP address and mask to `*` pattern glob, copied IP address of virtual machine from it via `ifconfig` (not from Win10 host `ipconfig`) and could mount to it from host.